# Program in Python to show letters guessed in a hangman game not working

Tags: python

I have to write a code in Python where it is about playing the game hangman. Currently my code cannot replace the "_" with the guessed letters properly, where it only replaces one and doesn't show all of the guessed letters.

My code is below:

```
import random

word = random.choice(["bread", "clouds", "plane"])

guess = 0
correct_guess = 0
play_again = True

print(word)
name = input("Hello, what's your name? ")
print('Hello', name)
status = input('Do you wish to play hangman? Yes/No ')
hyphens = print('_ ' * (len(word)))

if status == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':
  exit()

while play_again is True:

  letter = input('Guess a letter: ')

  if letter in word:
    guess = guess + 1
    correct_guess = correct_guess + 1
    print('You guessed a letter correctly!')
    position = word.find(letter)
    print("The letter is in position", position + 1, "out of", len(word), "in the word. Guess Count:", guess)
    if position == 0:
      print(letter, "_ _ _ _")
    if position == 1:
      print("_", letter, "_ _ _ ")
    if position == 2:
      print("_ _", letter, "_ _ ")
    if position == 3:
      print("_ _ _", letter, "_ ")
    if position == 4:
      print("_ _ _ _", letter)
  else:
    guess = guess + 1
    print("That letter isn't in the word. Guess Count:", guess)
  if guess == 10:
    print('Bad luck. You lost.')
    play = input('Do you want to play again? ')
    if play == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':
      exit()
  if correct_guess == 5:
    print('Congratulations! You have guessed the word! The word was', word + '.')
    play = input('Do you want to play again? ')
    if play == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':
      exit()
```

Your help is very much appreciated. Also, I don't know a lot about programming and I am fairly new to it.

James

Comment: first thing i noticed is this line `if status == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':` that will never work, you wan tit to be `if status in ['No', 'no', 'N', 'n']:`

Comment: There's so much wrong with this. Do you know what loops are? Do not print "_" manually, iterate or repeat (string *n prints the string n times). Store current game state in an array, check a guess in a loop and replace all letters that match in the current state (`if word[i] == letter: state[i] = letter`)...

Comment: I would highly recommend the use of methods to make the code easier to understand

Comment: Rather than writing the whole program and then realising there are errors you should write small testable bits of code and build up to the game. So write a function that takes a word and list of letters and prints the word in hangman form. Only then move onto the gameplay aspects of taking input.

Comment: the statement `if status == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':` should be `if status in ['No','no','N','n']:`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm still having trouble trying to show the hyphens and replace them with the letters guessed, where I can currently only show one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't write expression like :

```
if status == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':
```

the correct way is:

```
if play == 'No' or play == 'no' or play == 'N' or play == 'n':
```

or:

```
if play in ['No' ,'no', 'N' ,'n']
```

one solution:

```
import random

word = random.choice(["bread", "clouds", "plane"])


print(word)
name = input("Hello, what's your name? ")
print('Hello', name)
status = input('Do you wish to play hangman? Yes/No ')


def play():
    if status == 'No' or status == 'no' or status == 'N' or status == 'n':
        print ("Goodbye")
        return # exit 
    else:
        print('_ ' * (len(word))) # _ _ _ _ _ 

    guess = 0
    correct_guess = 0
    play_again = True

    pos_list = ['_' for x in range(len(word))] # define list where you will put your guessed letters ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
    while play_again is True:
      letter = input('Guess a letter: ')

      if letter in word:
        guess = guess + 1
        correct_guess = correct_guess + 1
        print('You guessed a letter correctly!')
        position = word.find(letter)
        print("The letter is in position", position + 1, "out of", len(word), "in the word. Guess Count:", guess)
        pos_list[position] = letter # save letter at position # ['_', '_', '_', 'a', '_']
        print (' '.join(pos_list)) # _ _ _ a _

      else:
        guess = guess + 1
        print("That letter isn't in the word. Guess Count:", guess)
      if guess == 10:
        print('Bad luck. You lost.')
        play = input('Do you want to play again? ')
        if play == 'No' or play == 'no' or play == 'N' or play == 'n':
            print("Goodbye")
            return
        else:
             print('_ ' * (len(word)))
      if correct_guess == len(word):
        print('Congratulations! You have guessed the word! The word was', word + '.')
        play = input('Do you want to play again? ')
        if play == 'No' or play == 'no' or play == 'N' or play == 'n':
            print("Goodbye")
            return
        else:
            print('_ ' * (len(word)))

play()
```

Comment: Hi..Probably this code does not find all instances of a guessed letter. Eg if the word is tapoa, the code will only find the "a" on position 2 and will miss the second "a"

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned it up a bit, removing duplicated code. Also that problematic condition:

```
if status == 'No' 'no' 'N' 'n':
```

Changed it to:

```
if status.lower().startswith("n"):
```

Also important to lower the letter input by the user. Here a full working code.

```
import random
import re

def start():
    status = input('Do you wish to play hangman? Yes/No ')
    if status.lower().startswith("n"):
        return True
    # Computer chooses word
    word = random.choice(["bread", "clouds", "plane"])
    # Setup game vars
    guess = []
    game_status = ["_"] * len(word)

    while True:
        print(" ".join(game_status))
        letter = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
        if letter in guess:
            print("You already tried that one.")
            continue
        guess.append(letter)
        if letter in word:
            print('You guessed a letter correctly!')
            positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(letter, word)]
            for pos in positions:
                game_status[pos] = letter
        else:
            print("That letter isn't in the word.")
        if len(guess) == 10:
            print(f'Bad luck {name}. You lost. The word was: {word}.')
            return
        if "_" not in game_status:
            print(f'Congratulations {name}! You have guessed the word! The word was {word}.')
            return

# Welcome
name = input("Hello, what's your name? ")
print('Hello', name)
while True:
    stop = start()
    if stop:
        break
print("Goodbye!")
```